# Disallow answered questions to be edited

Tags: feature-request, edits, voting, old-questions

Someone on ux.stackexchange.com is editing the questions that have his answer selected as the chosen answer, bringing them back up to the top.  Looks like an attempt to get more upvotes, but it's a disservice because it brings old answered questions up and pushes down new unanswered questions.  Sometimes the whole first page will be filled with old answered (answered by the same person) questions.

If editing an answered question wasn't possible, we wouldn't have this problem.  Another fix would be to not surface edited questions if they've already been answered.

Comment: only when ordered by activity, not by newest...

Comment: @hayden - that's the answer.  I didn't realize that option.  Would accept this as the answer if I could.

Answer (score 10):

What you should do here is just flag the question for moderator attention and let them know what's going on. There are far more legitimate uses for the behavior to stay as is than edge cases where one can abuse it, so it makes much more sense to simply stop the person that's doing so.

There are checks in place to discourage people from bumping by editing their *own* posts, wiki status is automatically applied once you do it enough. What could be happening is someone is aware of that, and bumping by editing the question instead.

In any event, it's something for the UX moderators to sort out, so the first step is to let them know something seems fishy.

Answer (score 3):

There are legitimate reasons one might need to edit an answered question, a primary one being changing the tags (conventions change over time).

So the proper thing to do to deal with a user abusing the system is to direct a comment at them (advising them to stop) and/or flag them for moderator attention so they can be dealt with (if their behavior is truly abusive and warrants moderator intervention).